# writing php code for checked checkboxes dynamically add by javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code as below to make a table:

```
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>

var table = document.getElementById('show_member');

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(i);
i = i+1;
// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the new <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = '$name';
cell2.innerHTML = '$name2';
cell3.innerHTML = '$lastname';
cell4.innerHTML = '$lastname2';
cell5.innerHTML = '$mellicode';
cell6.innerHTML = '$estekhdamnum';
cell7.innerHTML = '$email';
cell8.innerHTML = '$username';
cell9.innerHTML = '$password';
cell10.innerHTML = '$id';
var checkbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
***checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = 'mark[]';
checkbox.value = i-1;
cell11.appendChild(checkbox);***
</script>");
```

and a button as below:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="form-control" name = "karbar" id ="check" value="افزودن به لیست کاربران"onclick="add_karbar1()"/><br><br>
</div>
```

and below is my php code to update the table

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['karbar'])){
    //echo "<script>alert('was selected')</script>";
    foreach($_REQUEST['mark'] as $value){
        echo "<script>alert('$value was selected');</script>";
    }
}



?>
```

It gives me this error, why?

> Notice: Undefined index: mark in E:\Xampp_installed\htdocs\card\add_karbar.php on line 236
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Xampp_installed\htdocs\card\add_karbar.php on line 23

How can I recognize checked checkboxes and do php code for each checked checkbox in each row?

thanks

Comment: What does `$_REQUEST` look like?

Comment: what do you mean?
I searched in other sites and they said that you should use $_REQUEST to recognize checked check boxes and write php code in it.

Comment: Fine but if index `'mark'` is undefined need to inspect the `$_REQUEST` value to see why. Just dump the whole thing and see if it looks like you expect it to

Comment: I don't know what I should do

Comment: did you do a  dump of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php are two easy ways

Comment: it works but for sure I am not allowed to used php code in javascript
at the end because I couldn't do anything I decided to send it to another page, run the script of php I wanted and return it to the same page.
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably a javascript syntax error caused by the `***` that isn't allowing the script to reach the `checkbox.name = 'mark[]';` line. If that line does not execute, then there will be no `mark` variable in `$_REQUEST`. Change

```
***checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = 'mark[]';
checkbox.value = i-1;
cell11.appendChild(checkbox);***
```

to

```
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = 'mark[]';
checkbox.value = i-1;
cell11.appendChild(checkbox);
```

and see if it works

Comment: it works but for sure I am not allowed to used php code in javascript
at the end because I couldn't do anything I decided to send it to another page, run the script of php I wanted and return it to the same page.
thanks for your answer